# Getting Data from Web to put in Excel Sheet

Tags: javascript, excel

I am looking for a method to extract data from the results cards of my school from board website and put them in excel sheet automaticaly, and all i need to tell the system a range of roll numbers,

For Example. i want results from [www.fbise.edu.pk](http://www.fbise.edu.pk) by putting roll number in search box and then it open the results stores it in excel , and then iterate through all the range i have given.